# Does compiler saves argument of a function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a function which is loading image by index in another thread using GCD .

So lets assume this :

```
-(void)loadMainImageToIndex:(long)index
{
    NSDictionary *dic=[mainData objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *userImageUrl=[dic objectForKey:@"url"];
    NSURL *userUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:userImageUrl];
    [self downloadImageWithURL:userUrl completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSData *tdata)
     {
         if (succeeded)
         {

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^
                            {

                          //do something here 

                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                               {
                           //do something here that uses the index argument
```

And i call this function 3 times :

```
[self loadMainImageToIndex:0];
[self loadMainImageToIndex:1];
[self loadMainImageToIndex:2];
```

Question is, when the first call will end the thread operation , and will got to the point :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()
```

Will he see in there `index=0` , or will he see the last index was `called (==2)` ?

Question is, does he copy the whole function so when he finishes he can remember the argument that started the method ?
Another thing, does calling it 3 times at the same time, is a bad practice ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the actual full code in one piece? It's kinda hard to help with assumptions.

Comment: easily tested just NSLog index.

Comment: Yes NSLog it gave the right answer, but the whole GCD is a little "black box" for me, so i wanted to understand what is going on in there . and now i do:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short version: there's no problem here. You're doing fine and it'll behave like you would expect (each block will have the correct value).

Longer version:

```
-(void)loadMainImageToIndex:(long)index
```

Every call to this method will push a fresh copy of `index` onto the stack. It will be popped (destroyed) when the method returns. Even if this method is called many times in parallel (on different threads), each will have its own copy of `index` on its own stack. Local variables and arguments are private to a each call of a method or function.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^
```

The creation of a block here "captures" (copies) all the variables that it discovers within the block. That includes `index` because it's used by:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
```

So, there's no problem here. Your block that is sent to the main queue will have its own copy of `index`, which it made at the time the block was created. The enclosing block also made a copy of `index` at the time it was created, and the method made a copy of the value that was passed to it as `index`.

Note that "when a block is created" is the point at which the `^{}` is evaluated, not the point that `dispatch_` functions are called. Those functions accept a block, they don't create the block. It is completely legal (and common) to create a block and store it in a variable and later pass that block to something else. The block will capture (copy) its variables at the point that it's created. This concept is called a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29).

Comment: @Rob Napier , does calling it a few times to do a heavy job, is a bad practice? because i sometimes get a memory warning for this ..

Comment: Calling a function several times is no problem at all. The memory warning is a separate issue. It may be because your function allocates a lot of memory, so you may have to limit that (limited how many can run at the same time using `NSOperation` for instance). But managing memory usage is always an issue, even if you run things sequentially.